# NSLog a double* variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

```
- (void) _getPoints: (double*)arg1
{
  NSLog(@"%f", arg1);
}
```

This works for `double` and `float`, but not `double*`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to log the pointer or the value being pointed to?

Comment: Note that it's unusual to have a `double*` parameter unless it's so you can pass a modified value back to the caller.

Comment: Also, is there more to the real method? It's named with a `get` prefix but it doesn't return anything. And it makes no use of the pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `arg1` is pointing to some sort of double you want:

```
- (void) _getPoints: (double*)arg1
{
  NSLog(@"%f", *arg1);
}
```

You might want to refer to pointer tutorial to understand what is going on, such as [this](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch1x.htm).

Comment: Just to let people know, I am assuming he wants to print the value that `arg1` is pointing to...

Comment: Your assumption is true

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing `arg1` with `arg1 ? *arg1 :  @"null"`